# Mockito UnnecessaryStubbingException thrown after migrating from mockito-all to mockito-core

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

We migrated to a mockito-core in stead of mockito-all to be able to use the new fluent stubbing functionality. We also have a test-util-lib which contains a util to stub an InitialContext. In maven projects using this test-util-lib I suddenly get the `UnnecessaryStubbingException`.

This is the code:

```
public class WildFlyInitialContextFactory implements InitialContextFactory {

    private static final Map<String, Object> ENTRIES = new HashMap<>();
    private static Context context = initMock();

    static {
        System.setProperty( "java.naming.factory.initial", WildFlyInitialContextFactory.class.getName() );
    }

    private static Context initMock()  {

        Context context = null;
        try {
            context  = mock( Context.class );
            when( context.lookup( anyString() ) ).thenAnswer( invocation -> {
                if ( ENTRIES.containsKey( invocation.getArguments()[0] ) ) {
                    return ENTRIES.get( invocation.getArguments()[0] );
                }
                else {
                    throw new NamingException(  );
                }
            } );
        }
        catch (NamingException ex ) {
            LOG.error( ex );
        }
        return context;
    }

    public static void setEntry(String lookup, Object object) {
        ENTRIES.put( lookup, object );
    }

    @Override public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable<?, ?> arg0) {
        return context;
    }

}
```

I also tried the other way around (the doAnswer.when construction) with the same result. Note: I only want to trigger on a .lookup(String arg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Mockito when a test class is run, scans for unused mocks. This mock, (being a library mock that is initialized in a TestBase is not always called. The solution is to use `Mockito.lenient().when( context )` which has been added to later versions of Mockito.